# Separate the string and send the string values to list in java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a list `questionForm` and it contains `question_id`,`question`,`options` and I have taken options as a string separated by `|` symbol. Can anyone give me solution such that separate the string and display the options with radio buttons.

list contains

```
1
java is?

object oriented | Procedural | Asembly | Machin Level

2
Static block loaded?

Afer the class | Before the class | never | No such variable in java

3
Which is a reserved word in the Java programming language?


method | native | subclasses | reference



 <c:forEach var="opt" items="${questionForm}">
    <c:if test="${opt.question_id==1}">
    <script>
        check('${opt.question_type}','${opt.options}');
    </script>
    <td style="padding-left:200px;"> 
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

My javascript function is:

```
function check1(type,options){
    alert(type);
    var list = options;
    alert(list);
    if(type == "multiple choice"){
    alert(list);
    <% String values = "<script>document.writeln(list)</script>";
    List<String> opts = Arrays.asList(values.split("|"));
    out.println(opts);
    } 
}
```

and the expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

-------------SAMPLE TEST DATA-----------------

```
 ArrayList<Question> questionForm = new ArrayList<Question>();
    Question q1 = new Question(1, "multiple choice", "java is?", "object oriented | Procedural | Asembly | Machin Level" , 1);
    Question q2 = new Question(2, "multiple choice", "Static block loaded?", "Afer the class | Before the class | never | No such variable in java", 2);
    Question q3 = new Question(3, "multiple choice", "Which is a reserved word in the Java programming language?", "method | native | subclasses | reference", 2);
    questionForm.add(q1); questionForm.add(q2); questionForm.add(q3);

    request.setAttribute( "questionForm", questionForm );
```

-------------END / SAMPLE TEST DATA-----------------

### Question .java

```
public class Question {

private Integer question_id;
private String question_type;
private String question;
private String options;
private int answer;
...
```

}

### JSP CODE

```
<c:set var="radioNamelist" value="${fn:split('A,B,C,D,E', ',')}" scope="request" />


 <table style="float: left" >
            <c:forEach var="obj" items="${questionForm}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left">
        Q. <c:out value="${obj.question_id}" />. <c:out value="${obj.question}" />
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <c:if test="${obj.question_type=='multiple choice'}">
            <c:set var="options" value="${fn:split(obj.options, '|')}" />
            <c:forEach var="opt" items="${options}" varStatus="optStatus" >
                <tr> 
                    <td style="padding-left:30px;">
                       <input type='radio' name='opt${status.count}' value='${optStatus.count}' /> <c:out value="${radioNamelist[optStatus.count-1]}" />. <c:out value="${opt}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>          
        </c:if>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach> 
 </table>
```

Comment: you have given a good solution.but if i comment `<c:out value="${radioNamelist[optStatus.count-1]}" />` this tag it is showing only questions and answers but if i uncomment it, it is showing an exception like `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type java.lang.String
     at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:214)` can u resolve it

Comment: @asprin I have added <c:set var="radioNamelist" value="${fn:split('A,B,C,D,E', ',')}" scope="request" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String[] ar=values.split("|");
ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
{
     al.add(ar[i]);
}
```

Now by running Iterator() you can diplay in form of options